# Set product in shared Catalog

Tags: magento2, import, products

For product import,

I have checked from admin (admin -> catalog -> shared catalog ) that my id for shared catalog (Default (General)) is 1.

Then I done code as below. but not works. please guide me what I have missed

```
public function __construct(
    
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockStateInterface,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,

    \Magento\SharedCatalog\Model\ProductManagement $sharedCatalog
)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_productModel = $productModel;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_stockStateInterface = $stockStateInterface;
    $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->_categoryData = $this->getCategories();
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_attributeData = $this->getAttributes();
    $this->_sharedCatalog = $sharedCatalog;
}


private function saveProduct($productData = array())
{
  $sku = $productData['custom_material'];
  $productObj = $this->_productFactory->create();
  $productObj->setName($productData['custom_material_description']);

  other attributes ....


  $productObj->save();
  $this->_sharedCatalog->assignProducts(1, array($sku) );


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the ID of the shared catalog you need to assign to the products. If you know the shared catalog name, you can use a custom resource model that extends the `Magento\SharedCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\SharedCatalog`resource model, then add the following method:

```php
public function getSharedCatalogIdBySharedCatalogName(string $catalogName): int
{
    $stmt = $this->getConnection()
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable(), 'entity_id')
        ->where('name = ?', $catalogName);

    return $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($stmt);
}
```

2. In your custom code where you created the product(s), use the `vendor/magento/module-shared-catalog/Model/ProductManagement.php`'s  `assignProducts()` method to assign the product(s) by using as arguments the shared catalog ID retrieved at step 1. + the array of products which you want to assign (see how this is used inside `/vendor/magento/module-shared-catalog/Observer/Controller/SaveProduct.php`).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my code as you said. please help me if I miss anything

Comment: 1. you should inject an interface and not the concrete class for the product management, so try `Magento\SharedCatalog\Api\ProductManagementInterface` 2. i edited my answer above, you should add the array of product objects 3. make sure the b2b shared catalog functionality is enabled

Comment: Thank you very much... It works.

I have changed line 
    \Magento\SharedCatalog\Api\ProductManagementInterface $sharedCatalog

    and 
    
    $this->_sharedCatalog->assignProducts(1, [$productObj]);

Comment: Great, glad to hear this! Please mark the solution as accepted so that others ca use it too.